# Spring throwing Circular Reference Error with ObjectMapper and RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration

Tags: spring, jackson, spring-data-rest, objectmapper, circular-reference

I have a Spring Boot application (2.0.3) that's throwing a circular reference error involving objectMapper (faster.xml Jackson implementation, 2.9.6). It builds fine with Gradle (4.10.2), but upon deployment throws the following error:

```
...; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.leroyjenkins.service.common.config.CommonConfig':
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'objectMappers'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'objectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: 
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]:
Circular reference involving containing bean 'org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration' - 
consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'objectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException",
    "\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)",
```

The CommonConfig is referring to a configuration file I have:

```
@Configuration
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = . 
EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)
@EnableScheduling
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
@CompileStatic
@Slf4j
@Slf4jPlusMetrics("mlog")
class CommonConfig {

...

@Autowired List<ObjectMapper> objectMappers

@PostConstruct
void afterPropertiesSet() {
    log.info("initializing CommonConfig objectMappersSize={},contextPath={},threadPoolSize={},threadPoolQueueCapacity={},threadPoolDefaultTimeout={},appName={}",
        objectMappers.size(), contextPath, threadPoolSize, threadPoolQueueCapacity, threadPoolDefaultTimeout, appName)

    objectMappers.each { ObjectMapper objectMapper ->
        objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
        objectMapper.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
        objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JodaModule())
        objectMapper.registerModule(new GsnModelJacksonModule())
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
    }
}

...

}
```

We just updated to jdk11...not sure if that's relevant here.